# War File does not work properly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications, war

I have created a java web application using `Maven`. The application makes use of some resources (images). I run it with `Maven-> clean package` to create a `war file`. I deploy it using `Tomcat`. The war file works immaculately on my machine and two more machines in chrome  and in Internet-Explorer as well. Today we have tried it on a fourth machine and it presents the problem, that some resources are not included. All of us use `Tomcat 7` with the difference that the one on whose machine the war file does not work uses a little lower version of `Tomcat 7`. He insists though, that the problem is in the application and not in his server. What could a possible and justified reason for this inconsistency? Where do you think lies the source of the problem?

Comment: indeed the problem is with your application and not server. You may need to updgrade few class dependencies. Any error in stacktrace can explain further

Comment: What operating systems are the machines using? it could be caused by case-sensitivity, or by folder separators "/" vs "\", etc.

Comment: @GV: Why does it then run correctly in three machines? Do you mean with "class dependencies" dependencies in pom.xml? There is no error in stacktrace. Moreover we all use windows 8.

Comment: As you mentioned it didn't work on a lower version of tomcat. By class dependencies I mean the jars used in tomcat might have some change. But when there is know error, how do u know its not working?

Comment: @GV: I write in my question: It does not contain all the resources (images). Some of them are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The "war" file is as you guessed simply a package (a zip file in fact). You can unzip it and check what's inside to make sure the resources are there.

Also when you deploy it into tomcat, tomcat will itself unpack it into its webapps directory (or wherever it is pointing).

Make sure all the files are in the package and after you deploy all files are unpacked, then you can check for naming. There must be a difference, and I doubt is the tomcat version, but if you must you can upgrade tomcat and try again.
It may also be some cache, maybe you were working in your tomcat server for a while and you have the resources there from previous deploys you didn't clean up properly. Stop tomcat, delete your application directory, copy the war file and start tomcat again for a clean deploy in all servers. (hot deployment in tomcat can be quite dodgy and buggy)

I don't think I can give a solving answer considering the lack of details but I hope I helped in some way.